# Can't find my bidimensional array on a movie clip AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, multidimensional-array

I'm new on AS3 and I'm having troubles to read a bidimensional array created after reading a xml. Here is the code:

```
var countdowns:Array = new Array;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("products.xml");
xmlLoader.load(url);
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoad);
function onXmlLoad(e:Event):void
{
  var xml = new XML(xmlLoader.data);
  var productElements:XMLList = xml.product;
  var len:int = productElements.length();

    for (var i:int = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        var productElement:XML = productElements[i];

        countdowns[productElements[i].name] = new Array;
        countdowns[productElements[i].name]["name"] = productElements[i].name;
        countdowns[productElements[i].name]["user"] = productElements[i].user;
        countdowns[productElements[i].name]["image"] = productElements[i].image;
        countdowns[productElements[i].name]["fondo"] = productElements[i].fondo;
    }
    trace("Productos: "+countdowns["ambar"]["image"])}
```

This works like a charm. But when I want to trace it in the next frame it gives me an error. Years ago I used to do `_level0 vars` so I can trace them with `trace(_level0.countdowns["ambar"]["image"])` but it seems that `trace(MovieClip(root).countdowns["ambar"]["image"])` doesn't do the same. Where is my bidimensional array? How can I access to it from other movieclips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your issue is that the next frame is reached prior to your xml finishing to load.

Since `xmlLoader.load` is asynchronous, your program will move on to the next frame even if it hasn't loaded yet (which in the span of 1 frame it will never load that fast).

To rectify this, just put a `stop` on your first frame (or whatever frame this code is on),  then `play()` (or `nextFrame()`) inside the `onXmlLoad` function.

Comment: Thank you @BadFeelingAboutThis, this big-little thing has made everything work. I knew i was forgetting something simple like this!

Answer (score 2):

Let's get straight into it. There are a number of problems here:

1) Missing parenthesis when instantiating Array. It should be:

```
var countdowns:Array = new Array();
```

Or the literal which is neater and slightly faster:

```
var countdowns:Array = [];
```

2) You're adding your load listener AFTER calling load(). But since your 'on complete' listener is only added afterwards, if the load was to complete immediately then your listener might never be triggered. You should always add listeners before calling the method that might trigger the events:

```
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoad);
xmlLoader.load(url);
```

3) No need to allocate memory to a variable that you're not using. You don't need the url variable as this will do fine:

```
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("products.xml"));
```

4) You're using strings (i.e. "ambar") as the names of the product elements, yet using those as indexes for your countdowns array:

```
countdowns[productElements[i].name] = new Array();
```

Arrays aren't indexed with strings - they're indexed with numbers like this:

```
countdowns[i] = new Array();
```

If you want to use strings then you should use an object or dictionary like this:

```
var countdowns:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
countdowns[productElements[i].name] = new Array();
```

5) Check out 'for each' which will give you a more compact loop.

Comment: in regards to #1, parenthesis are actually not required in AS3/JS for instantiation, though I would say they make code more readable.

Comment: in regards to #4,   arrays actually can be indexed with strings in EcmaScript based languages like AS3/JS.    AS3 didn't always have a native Dictionary type, so it's fairly common to see string indexed arrays in AS3 code examples people find around the web.

Comment: Thanks @Gareth! The BadFeelingAboutThis solution made the script work, but all this information is very helpful to me for right coding.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis, if you assign a value to an array using a string index and then compile with the Flex SDK, you will rightly see that the array is empty because the assignment is invalid.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis, with regards to omitting the parentheses, yes it will still work in this case because the ECMAscript specification allows for it to be omitted if no constructor arguments are required. But to an obvious learner this is an unnecessary distraction IMO.